# Identifying if one field is partial derived from another in R

Tags: r

So given a pattern, say two letters, and the position of the pattern, is it a prefix, suffix or in the middle, I need to identify if a field is partial derived from another. So for example given the following dataset

```
 data.V1 data.V2
1       GH  GH1001
2       FD  FD2002
3       TH  2345TH
4       ED ED56763
5       US  4345US
6       FG F6736tG
```

if LL is the pattern for column one where LL refers to two letters in this case. If the pattern for column 2 is LL#. This indicates that the position of the pattern is the first elements of each element in row 2. So in the dataset above rows 1,2&4 would obey the pattern.

I have tried if then statements but these did not work if the pattern was in the middle , #LL#. I have also tried the function regmathes but that did not work either.

Comment: [Useful link](https://regexr.com/) for trying out and better understanding regular expressions

Comment: For example, in the link above, try ``[A-Z]{2}``, ``^[A-Z]{2}`` and ``[A-Z]{2}$`` for various entries.

Comment: @Nutle thanks. Is it possible in regular expressions to specify where to start? For example if I wanted to check were the 3rd and 4th elements of an entry both letters.

Comment: ``^`` for beginning, ``$`` for the end, ``.`` as a filler. So for the *exactly* third and 4th, try ``..[A-Z]{2}``, note the two dots. Finally, questions with regex are very easily googleable, since they're a common standard everywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
apply(df,1,function(x) grepl(paste0("^",x["data.V1"]),x["data.V2"]))
```

For every row (that's the 1 in apply), this will check whether the contents of data.V1 appears right at the beginning of data.V2 (`^` means the beginning of a string for regular expressions).

Result:

```
    1     2     3     4     5     6 
 TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Replace the grepl first argument with the following for:

```
End of string: paste0(x["data.V1"],"$")
Middle of string: paste0(".+",x["data.V1"],".+")
After n characters (n defined elsewhere): paste0(".{",n,"}",x["data.V1"])
```

(for the last one, the form "{n}" means the last character is repeated n times. Since it is preceded by ".", it means any n characters.)

Comment: Thanks.That worked great if the pattern was at the beginning. Would it be possible to do something similar if the pattern was in the middle or end of a entry? For example row 5 in the dataset above.

Comment: see the edited answer above: just replace the first argument of the grepl with either option.

Comment: @ iod. Just wondering is it possible to generalize the statement. For example I tried  apply(data,1,function(x) grepl(paste0('rep(.,n)+',x["V1"],'...+'),x["V3"])). So that I can specify the position outside the function.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve with that rep() call. As noted in the comments to your question - it's a good idea to familiarize yourself with regex syntax.

Comment: depending on the patterns the desired characters could be 2 or 4 characters in. I do not want to another function each time. I would like to specify the number of characters outside the function and use the same function each time.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, in that case, the code you used is accurate, except that that "rep(.,n)" shouldn't be in quotation marks. I'll add another way of writing it in the answer above in a minute.